# How to add multiple Text view and edittext in dialog alert

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, textview

I want to create a dialog alert as it show in android when we tap on a wi-fi to get connect to the wi-fi. I have create d a dialog alert but its not showing all the textview and edittext. Please help

here's my code

```
AlertDialog.Builder password = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        password.setTitle("Connect to Network");

        final TextView ssid = new  TextView(context);
        ssid.setText(wifiScanList.get(position).SSID);
        password.setView(ssid);
        final TextView bssid=new TextView(context);
        bssid.setText(wifiScanList.get(position).BSSID);
        password.setView(bssid);
        final TextView capab=new TextView(context);
        capab.setText(wifiScanList.get(position).capabilities);
        password.setView(capab);
        final EditText pass =new  EditText(context);
        password.setView(pass);     

        password.setPositiveButton("Connect", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                checkPassword= pass.getText().toString();
                finallyConnect(checkPassword, position);
                dialog.dismiss();


            }
        });
        password.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog passdialog = password.create();
        passdialog.show();
```

Comment: @rogerthatcode i haven't used xml code to create dialog alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is to design your custom dialog in a separated xml file let's say

> customdialog.xml in your R/layout folder

and from your Activity you can create a new AlertDialog and apply your theme to it this way

```
// Create custom dialog object
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
                // Set dialog title
                dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
               // here you can get the reference to your Views and do whatever you want with
```

Comment: but i want  buttons at the as we get in alerdialog and using xml i cant enable those buttons. Can you  tell me how add those button in xml